# Java server handling data - Receive and send data

Tags: java, networking

I have started java not that long ago, and I was wondering, if I want to make a GUI, and then I want the gui to display some data, I can't have mysql connection in that gui, it's a very big security exploit, therefore I've thought about making a java server that receives packets, and sends back data.

I know PHP HTTP callbacks are the best for this, but I really want to get into the server/networking in java.

Is there any library that offers such thing? Tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/), [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/), or [Netty](http://netty.io/). [Here's Sun's sockets tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) if you want to learn from the ground up. Grizzly and Mina use Java NIO which is confusing to a beginner. Might want to start with the tutorial.

Out of the 3 frameworks I suggested, I've only used Netty for a project. I read Netty was lower level, and had more speed 6 months ago. It worked well for me.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how it goes for you. I'm rusty on Netty but I might be able to assist with questions on it.

Comment: First I am going to read alot out of Sun's tutorials about sockets, seems interesting to be honest, and proper for beginners.

Comment: That's the right place to start. If you have network programming experience it will be pretty straightforward.